# link_to edit page default path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails3 to build a simple customer information page (in table format). On this page user can edit each customer's detailed information. It's possible for each customer to have multiple records. I use link_to to get to the edit page:

```
<td class="edit" id="edit">edit
<%= link_to 'edit', :action => :edit, :cust_id => ci.cust_id %>
</td>
```

edit.html.erb:

```
<h1>Editing cust</h1>
<%= form_for(@cust_info) do |cust| %>
    Customer: <%= cust.text_field :cust_schema %>
    <%= cust.submit "Save" %>
<% end%>
```

In my controller, I have this:

```
def edit
            cust_id = params[:cust_id]
            @cust_info = CustInfo.find(:all, :conditions => ["cust_id = ?", cust_id])
end
```

The customer info page shows right. When I click the edit link, I got the error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `cust_info_cust_info_path' for #<#<Class:0x7fb0857ce7b8>:0x7fb0857ca780>):
    1: <h1>Editing cust</h1>
    2: 
    3: <%= form_for(@cust_info) do |cust| %>
    4:  Customer: <%= cust.text_field :cust_schema %>
    5:  <%= cust.submit "Save" %>
    6: <% end%>
  app/views/track/edit.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_track_edit_html_erb___102324197_70198065248580_0'
```

Where does `cust_info_cust_info_path' come from?

EDIT: here is the code in the controller:

```
class TrackController < ApplicationController

def display
end

def information
end


def customerinfo
    @cust_info = CustInfo.find(:all, :order=>"cust_id")
    @cust_info.each do |ci|
                    if ci.upload_freq == 'W'
                            ci.upload_freq = 'Weekly'
                    elsif ci.upload_freq == 'M'
                            ci.upload_freq = 'Monthly'
                    end

    end

end


def edit
    cust_id = params[:cust_id]
    @cust_info = CustInfo.find(:all, :conditions => ["cust_id = ?", cust_id])

end
```

end
end

Answer (score 0):

Change `@cust_info = CustInfo.find(:all, :conditions => ["cust_id = ?", cust_id])`

to

`@cust_info = CustInfo.find(cust_id)`

Comment: what's your reason of doing that? I actually tried that before. And I got error: NoMethodError (undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/track_controller.rb:163:in `edit'. I thought both should work, but I haven't figured out why I got this error.

Comment: `find(:all)` will return an Array. `find(id)` will return the object matching that ID, or `nil`. You would have to post the contents of `track_controller.rb` for more insight into how the next set of errors is to be tackled. This line no longer has errors.

Comment: Actually, `find(id)` will not return `nil`, it will return a `RecordNotFound` error if, as the name implies, a record is not found. If you want it to return `nil` instead of `RecordNotFound`, you'd need to do `find_by_id(id)`.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. However, it shouldn't return nil in this case. I saw the log and when I use find(:all, :condition => cust_id=cust_id), there were actually items returned. I'm gonna put my controller logic inside the question.

Comment: `CustInfo.find_by_id(cust_id)` is equivalent to `CustInfo.find(:first, :conditions => ["id = ?", cust_id])`...u see here column `id` is searched instead of column `cust_id`..you say there are more than one record for a customer..can u explain your models and database schema?

Comment: I finally figured out why find(id) doesn't work but find(:all, :condition) works. Because I don't have a primary key set in my model. So after I put in this: set_primary_key :cust_id, find(id) works now. My Rails error message is now changed to 
    undefined method `cust_info_path' for #<#<Class:0x7fe21a4c0fc8>:0x7fe21a4bf3d0> from 
    undefined method `cust_info_cust_info_path' for #<#<Class:0x7fb0857ce7b8>:0x7fb0857ca780>)